# Pattern for infrequently used UI in desktop application

Tags: buttons, desktop-application, tabs

I have a desktop application where the user will paste some text into a textbox located within the tab that is initially displayed to the user.

The CONVERT button will become enabled when text is input into the textbox.

When the user clicks the CONVERT button, the pasted text will be transformed into a more structured form and presented to the user in the other tab.  The tab transition will happen as part of the CONVERT button being clicked.

Once this process is over, the initial tab with the original pasted text will rarely be referenced.  But it will be there if the original text needs to be consulted.

Is this still a viable UI in 2021?  I am somewhat old-school and would like to know if a new/better pattern exists.  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Don't know what tools or ui framework you are using but you can use collapsible areas like in the picture to show both version on same area without tabbed interface. Provided it is achievable in your ui framework.

Comment: Good idea, this is more modern.  I am working in WPF.